# Designing a save file for an application

Tags: java, file-io

Assume you have an JAVA application which processes some input (ranging 1 - 5 GBs) and saves the output (~100s MBs) to a file in an **append only** environment like HDFS.

The basic structure of the file is as follows

- set of values (most of the data)
- Set of keys
- some metadata

keys and values are similar concepts to a Map Reduce paradigm.

Since the amount of data written to file is huge, it is better to dump of chunks of the file to disk when possible. What are good ways of designing such a file format to keep it flexible for later releases? How do we maintain versions of the file format in Java?

Any good resources/links would be helpful too! I am trying to understand best practices for creating your own custom file format with the above constraints.

Thanks !

Comment: Are your values fixed in size?

Comment: No. They can vary depending on the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered Apache Avro?

http://avro.apache.org/docs/1.3.0/index.html